# AddTarget on UIButton not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewDataSource` defined as follows.

```
class MyDataSource : NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var tables : [Table]?


...


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell: TableCVCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableCVCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let table = tables![row]
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if table.type == "book" {
            cell.actionButton.table = table
            cell.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

@objc func btnClicked(sender : ActionButton) {
    print("clicked")
} 

}
```

I'm trying to assign a target for my `actionButton`, however nothing happens when I click it. I made sure to enable `isUserInteractionEnabled` for the cell and the `actionButton`.

EDIT:

`MyDataSource` is used here in my `UIView` definition:

```
class MyView: UIView {

var collectionView : UICollectionView!
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cvDelegate = MYDelegate()
    let dataSource = MyDataSource()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupCollectionView()
    }

func setupCollectionView() {
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.delegate = cvDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        collectionView.register(TableCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

and finally:

```
MyViewController : UIViewController {
 override func loadView() {
        let view = MyView()
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you make use of this `MyDataSource` class. And have you verified that the call to `addTarget` is actually being reached?

Comment: @rmaddy I did - tested it with a breakpoint - also see my coment on Sh_Khan's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `isUserInteractionEnabled`

```
collectionView.delegate = cvDelegate
collectionView.dataSource = dataSource 
collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Should be `true` or remove it as by default it's `true`

```
collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: so currently in my higher level view where the `UiCollectionView` is defined I have `let dataSource = MyDataSource() collectionView.dataSource = dataSource`

Comment: this code in `viewDidLoad` ?? if so move the datasource line as a var

Comment: it's not - it's on top of the file where all the views are defined.

Comment: can you share all the relevant code ? sure `if table.type == "book" {` hits ??

Comment: The proposed change for `MyViewController` isn't right. 1) UIViewController already has a `view` property. 2) The original `view` property is already a strong reference.

Comment: the `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the collectionView fixed it - didn't need the view